# Select columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-database

I have multiple tables with identical primary key fields but no other identical field. I want to select a collection of columns from all tables matching a specific primary key, something like so:

```
SELECT T1.a, T2.b, ..., TN.z FROM T1, T2, ..., TN WHERE T1.pk = "abc"
```

Comment: Have you tried using `join`?  `select ... from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.a, T1.b, ..., TN.z
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.pk = T2.pk
INNER JOIN T3 on T1.pk = T3.pk
...
INNER JOIN TN on T1.pk = TN.pk
AND TN.pk = "abc"
```

Or in a shorter form (thanks @Abelisto!).

```
SELECT T1.a, T1.b, ..., TN.z
FROM T1 JOIN T2 using(pk)
JOIN T3 using(pk)
...
JOIN TN using(pk)
WHERE TN.pk = "abc"
```

Comment: There are several things allowing to make query shorter: joins is inner by default in Postgres, so `INNER JOIN` is equal to `JOIN`; if columns have same names then it is possible to write `t1 join t2 using(pk)` instead of `t1 join t2 on t1.pk=t2.pk`